# How do I make a print and organize a specific part of a variable at the same time

Tags: python

Heres an example of each ID

```py
ID001 = {
    'Name': 'A Dull Rusty Sword',
    'Weight': 5,
    'Price': 105,
    'Acc': 0,
    'Str': 3,
    'Dex': 0,
    'Hp': 0,
    'MagDmg': 0,
    'LevReq': 1
}
```

This is the list:

```py
invintory = (ID001,ID002,ID003,ID004,ID005,ID006,ID007,ID008,ID009,ID010,ID011,)
```

This is the code Im struggling with:

```py
 for i, item in enumerate(invintory):
          print("%d: %s" % (i, item))
```

I need it to print the list but only the name of each ID, I've tryed everything and on my last resort.

```
0: {'Name': 'A Dull Rusty Sword', 'Weight': 5, 'Price': 105, 'Acc': 0, 'Str': 3, 'Dex': 0, 'Hp': 0, 'MagDmg': 0, 'LevReq': 1}
1: {'Name': '2 Dull Rusty Daggers', 'Weight': 2, 'Price': 90, 'Acc': 0, 'Str': 3, 'Dex': 0, 'Hp': 0, 'MagDmg': 0, 'LevReq': 1}
2: {'Name': 'A Broken Mace', 'Weight': 3, 'Price': 85, 'Acc': 0, 'Str': 2, 'Dex': 0, 'Hp': 0, 'MagDmg': 0, 'LevReq': 1}
3: {'Name': 'A Wooden Bow', 'Weight': 1, 'Price': 110, 'Acc': 0, 'Str': 0, 'Dex': 3, 'Hp': 0, 'MagDmg': 0, 'LevReq': 1}
4: {'Name': 'A Wooden Crossbow', 'Weight': 4, 'Price': 95, 'Acc': 0, 'Str': 0, 'Dex': 3, 'Hp': 0, 'MagDmg': 0, 'LevReq': 1}
5: {'Name': 'An Old Slingshot', 'Weight': 1, 'Price': 85, 'Acc': 0, 'Str': 0, 'Dex': 4, 'Hp': 0, 'MagDmg': 0, 'LevReq': 1}
6: {'Name': 'An Old Wooden Staff', 'Weight': 4, 'Price': 65, 'Acc': 0, 'Str': 0, 'Dex': 0, 'Hp': 0, 'MagDmg': 1, 'LevReq': 0}
7: {'Name': 'A Hide Hat', 'Weight': 6, 'Price': 100, 'Acc': 0, 'Str': 0, 'Dex': 0, 'Hp': 1, 'MagDmg': 0, 'LevReq': 0}
8: {'Name': 'A Pair of Hide Gloves', 'Weight': 6, 'Price': 100, 'Acc': 0, 'Str': 0, 'Dex': 0, 'Hp': 1, 'MagDmg': 0, 'LevReq': 0}
9: {'Name': 'A Pair of Hide Boots', 'Weight': 6, 'Price': 100, 'Acc': 0, 'Str': 0, 'Dex': 0, 'Hp': 1, 'MagDmg': 0, 'LevReq': 0}
10: {'Name': 'A Hide Tunic', 'Weight': 6, 'Price': 100, 'Acc': 0, 'Str': 0, 'Dex': 0, 'Hp': 1, 'MagDmg': 0, 'LevReq': 0}
```

Current output above
And this is what I want it to do

```
0: A Dull Rusty Sword
1: 2 Dull Rusty Daggers
2: A Broken Mace
ect ect ect
```

Comment: Instead of printing `item`, print `item['Name']`.